# Chomp Game- do I have winning strategy?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

for those who don't know the game: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomp
short review- you have choclate table n x m with 1 poisoned cubed in the bottom left corner.
The player target is to avoid eating that cube. Each player in his turn choose 1 cube and actualy eat all the cubes that are right and up to that cube.

With a given matrix n X m and a list that represent the configuration of the game;
Each index represent how many cubes are in each column. For example: [3,3,2,2]-         (the player chose to eat the second cube from the right)

P=poisoned

1. X X
2. X X X X
3. P X X X

(the numbers are just for the order)

I need to recursivley return an answer wheater there is a winning strategy or not for the player that it's turn to play. I thought about this: If I can know that for the next step (player against me) there's no winning strategy- I have winning strategy. stop terms are: if 1 last cube left- return false; if 2 last cubes left- return true. Just have hard times how to return it recursivley in a way that will give me an answer for that question

I thought about calculating all the moves that the player can do, but I couldn't implement that solution... any help?

Comment: what about N, M constraints?

Comment: what complexity u need?